# return a lookup table for an html select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Suppose in the HTML there is a select menu and I want a lookup table representing the values and descriptions in the menu.

```
<select id="carMenu">
    <option value="P">Park</option>
    <option value="R">Reverse</option>
    <option value="N">Neutral</option>
    <option value="D">Drive</option>
</select>
```

Now one way to construct a lookup table in Javascript/JQuery is as follows:

```
var lookup = {}; $('#carMenu>option').map(function()
{ 
    lookup[this.value]=this.innerHTML; 
})
```

Obtaining

```
{
    P: "Park", 
    R: "Reverse", 
    N: "Neutral", 
    D: "Drive"
}
```

Is there a jQuery method to generate this object directly -- instead of iterating over an externally supplied object?

Comment: You're not really using `.map()` correctly. You might as well use `.each()` or a `for` loop in place there.

Comment: @MattBall I know.  Returning something from the map will result an array of some sort, which will then need to be further transformed to get an object.  Wanting an object directly instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such jQuery function which gives you an object rather than an array. It would be pretty darn simple to write one yourself, though. It's just a matter of taking what you've already written and encapsulating it in a jQuery function:

```
$.fn.mapToObject = function (callback) {
    var output = {};

    this.each(function (index, element) {
        var toAdd = callback.call(this, index, element);
        output[toAdd.key] = toAdd.value;
    });

    return output;
};
```

...which you could then call like this:

```
var lookup = $('#carMenu>option').mapToObject(function (index, element) {
    return {
        key: this.value,
        value: this.innerHTML
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/nQXL2

Comment: Not surprised in the least that the vanilla `for` loop is faster than the jQuery `.each()`. jQuery isn't used for its speed.

Comment: it was a friendly way of saying that performance-critical functions should always be implemented in vanilla JS =P

Comment: Indeed. And if you're using jQuery for a given task, you're almost certainly not concerned with raw performance. I deliberately chose to use that inner `.each()`, knowing full well there are faster ways to iterate, because it's idiomatic in the context.

Comment: In the context of rational HTML there should not usually be more than a few dozen matches, so code clarity is preferred to speed.  Thanks for showing me how easy it is to write a jQuery extension.  Probably about time I looked at that....

Answer (score 1):

`map` is not the right function for what you want to achieve and I don't think `jQuery` provides a way of doing that. However, you could easily create your own function for that either as a `jQuery` plugin or not.

http://jsfiddle.net/scarsick/qG5Dc/1/ (with your example)

```
function makeMap(o, fn) {
    var map = {}, r;

    if (typeof o.length === 'number') {
        for (var i = 0, len = o.length; i < len; i++) {
            map[(r = fn(i, o[i]))[0]] = r[1];
        }
        return map;
    }

    for (var k in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            map[(r = fn(k, o[k]))[0]] = r[1];
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

**With an `array`**

```
var map = makeMap([1, 2, 3, 4], function (i, v) { return ['item' + i, v]; });
console.log(map); // {item0: 1, item1: 2, item2: 3, item3: 4}
```

**With a `jQuery` object**

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>first item</li>
    <li>second item</li>
    <li>third item</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
var map = makeMap($('ul li'), function (i, v) {
    return ['li' + i, v.innerHTML];
});

console.log(map); // {li0: "first item", li1: "second item", li2: "third item"}
```

**With a plain `object`**

```
var map = makeMap({prop1: 'test', prop2: 'test'}, function (k, v) {
    return [k.toUpperCase(), v];
});
console.log(map); // {PROP1: "test", PROP2: "test"}
```